# Solving a modular equation (Python)

Tags: python, modulus, equation-solving

I have what seems to be an easy problem to solve in Python, but as I am new to python I am unaware on how to solve this.

All I am trying to solve is...

`(x * e) mod k = 1`   (where `e` and `k` are known values)

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Comment: `(x*e) mod K = 1` or `x * (e mod k) = 1` ?

Comment: Sorry (x*e) mod k = 1

Comment: Do I assume correctly you're talking about modular arithmetic not just simple `%` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching for `x` is basically looking for inverse element of `e` mod `k` which can be done by  [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) which nicely implemented and used for [modular inverse here](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Modular_inverse):

```python
# Iterative Algorithm (xgcd)
def iterative_egcd(a, b):
    x,y, u,v = 0,1, 1,0
    while a != 0:
        q,r = b//a,b%a; m,n = x-u*q,y-v*q # use x//y for floor "floor division"
        b,a, x,y, u,v = a,r, u,v, m,n
    return b, x, y

def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = iterative_egcd(a, m) 
    if g != 1:
        return None
    else:
        return x % m
```

<sub>Note: I don't own the code</sub>

And usage:

```python
>>> e = 3
>>> k = 7
>>> x = modinv(e,k)
>>> x
5
>>> e*x % k
1
```

Answer (score 4):

Since [**Python 3.8**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow), the simple way is now:

```py
pow(e, -1, k) # x is the output of this statement
```

Example:

```py
>>> pow(38, -1, 97)
23
>>> 23 * 38 % 97 == 1
True
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would prefer to use the popular math library [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) instead of coding your own algorithm, then the function to solve your equation (i.e., finding the modular inverse) is called invert().  After installing the current version of gmpy (version 2 as of this writing), you would simply do this:

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> x = gmpy2.invert(e, k) # (Supply e and k here)
```

Note: gmpy will return the value in its native mpz (multi-precision integer) format, however you can treat the value just like a regular int in Python code without problem, or if you prefer, cast it to an int explicitly:

```
>>> x = int(gmpy2.invert(3, 7))
```

Here is the documentation for gmpy2.invert():

> invert(x, m) -> mpz
>
> Return y such that x*y == 1 (mod m). Raises ZeroDivisionError if no
>   inverse exists.

The advantage to this approach is that the gmpy algorithm is fast and you don't need to type any extra code.  The disadvantage is you have to import a third-party module.

Comment: `x = int(sympy.invert(3, 7))` works too, for those who have problems getting `gmpy2` (like me) but do have access to `sympy`